# Why do parentheses make - a + when $x^2+x-x-1$ is changed to $(x^2+x)-(x+1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binary-operations

I know that the equations are equivalent by doing the math with the same value for x, but I don't understand the rules for changing orders or operations.
When it is not the first addition or subtraction happening in the equation, parentheses make the addition subtraction and vice versa? Are there any other rules?

$x^2+x-x-1 = (x^2+x)-(x+1)$?

What if you put the parentheses around the two $x$s in the middle?
$x^2+(x-x)+1$? Should that be (x+x) in the middle?

Comment: You could think of subtracting $(x+1)$ as adding $-1\cdot(x+1)$; distribute the $-1$

Comment: No you can't call $+(x - x)$ as $+(x + x)$, because there is a *plus sign* in front. You only change the signs over when there's a minus sign in front.

Answer (score 2):

Think of subtracting $(x+1)$ as adding $-1\cdot(x+1)$.

Then apply the distributive property, so it's adding $-1\cdot x + -1\cdot 1=-x-1$.

When you add $(x-x)$, it should be $(x-x)$, not $x+x$, because there's no $-1$ to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

The sign before the parenthesis distributes to the content:

$$\begin{align}+(a+b)&=a+b\\-(a+b)&=-a-b\\+(a-b)&=a-b\\-(a-b)&=-a+b.\end{align}$$

Comment: "sign before the parenthesis distributes to the content" What if it was $-a-b+c$? Would that become $-(a+b-c)$? I'm trying to figure out the rule. Does the first sign reverse every + and/ or - in the parenthesis? $-a+b-c+d-e+f-g$ (another example).

Comment: The short answer is: yes, that is the case. Draw pictures if you think it makes it easier, and imagine that when you bracket something together, you treat it as an expression that is "all in one lump".

Comment: @Renoldus: *distributes* means what it says.

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple general rule for bracket notation: $-(a+b)=-a-b$. It's more or less a definition

Comment: "general rule for bracket notation" But, what if it was the first part of an equation? It would still change a-b to a+b? For example, what would $-a-b+c-d+e be if you only put brackets around a and b? I thought this was about orders of operations, but all the answers are saying this is distribution.

Comment: if you put brackets only around $a$ and $b$ then  $-a-b+c-d+e = -(a+b) +c+d+e$. the "-" acts only on "what is in the bracket". $c,d,e$ are not in the bracket, so "-" does not touch them. Alternatively you can think of it as distibution law in a ring that contains integers (ie integers $\mathbb{Z}$ itself). That's what Tanner below wrote

Comment: You meant c-d in your example? I think I get it now. Thank you.

Comment: yes, it was indeed a typo of mine, sorry. But as I said, "-" acts only on what is in the bracket. In yor example $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify it, and suppose you have $x^2 - x - 1$.

Examine what you are doing. You start with $x^2$.

Then you subtract $x$ from $x^2$.

Then you subtract $1$ from what you have got after the previous step, that is, $x^2 - x$.

So you have subtracted first $x$, then $1$, from $x^2$.

What have you in total removed from $x^2$?  You have removed $x$ and $1$, that is, $x+1$, from $x^2$.

So subtracting $x$ and then $1$ from $x^2$ is exactly the same as subtracting $x + 1$ from $x^2$.

There you see, $x^2 - x - 1 \equiv x^2 - (x + 1)$.

You can do it generally, and see that $a - b - c \equiv a - (b + c)$, whatever $a$, $b$ and $c$ are.