# I saw steps in an equation that added a 1 and a -1. Why is this okay?

Tags: linear-algebra, factoring

$(x^2+x)-(x+1)$=
$(x \cdot x + x \cdot 1)+(-1)\cdot(x+1)$

Does this have to be a multiplication by +1 and -1? I'm not sure why the - in the middle changed to a + when the (-1) appeared.

(Sorry I don't know the notation for the dot)

Comment: What do the dots represent?  Are you trying to write $\times$ or $\cdot$ to represent multiplication?

Comment: Not the 'x' but a dot. Yes. What is the notation for that? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Well, I 'm still not sure I understand what the right side means.  The left side, on the other hand, is just $x^2+x-x-1=x^2-1$.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Comment: Thank you. Will update the dots. And I missed an 'x' in the OP for the the 'right', now second factoring of the equation.

Comment: To be clear:  there is no "factoring" involved here, at least not in what I wrote.  I just simplified the expression on the left side.  One could then factor the final answer, as $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: Looks like follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700938/why-do-parentheses-make-a-when-x2x-x-1-is-changed-to-x2x-x1)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why the - in the middle changed to a + when the (-1) appeared.

By definition,
$$a - b := a + (-b) = a + (-1)\cdot b\;,$$
whereas $(-b) = (-1)\cdot b$ is the inverse element of $b$. You could also have written
$$\begin{split}(x^2 + x) - (x+ 1) &= (x\cdot x + x\cdot 1) - 1\cdot (x + 1)\end{split} $$

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to keep track of everything if you use a number instead of the variable $x$. If we substitute $x = 3$, the equation becomes
$$
(3^2+3)-(3+1) = (3 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 1)+(-1)\cdot(3+1).
$$
It's easy to see that $(3^2 + 3)$ is the same as $(3 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 1)$.  $3 \cdot 3$ and $3^2$ are both just $9$, and multiplying $3 \cdot 1$ just leaves us with $3$. So, $3^2 + 3$ and $3 \cdot 3 + 3\cdot 1$ are both just $9+3 = 12$.

Now, on the left side we're supposed to take $12$ and subtract $3 + 1$. On the right side, we're supposed to take $12$ and add $(-1)\cdot (3+1)$. In other words, on one side we subtract $4$, and on the other we add $-4$.
Can you see why these operations lead to the same result?

The point now is that there's nothing special about the number $3$ here; this would work if we plugged anything else in. In other words, it is always true that $x^2 = x \cdot x$, that $x \cdot 1 = x$, and that adding $(-1)\cdot (x+1)$ is the same as subtracting $x+1$. So, it is indeed true that
$$
(x^2 + x) - (x+1) = (x\cdot x + x\cdot 1) + (-1) \cdot (x+1).
$$

Comment: But, why can you insert a * 1 and -1 to the equation? It doesn't seem to work with other numbers. You couldn't replace the added * 1 and -1 with *4 and -4. Are both the *1 and the -1 needed here?

Comment: You can multiply by $1$ because multiplying by $1$ does not change the given value; the number $1$ is special in this way.  For instance, $3 \cdot 1$ is the same a $3$, but if we multiply by any other number (for instance, $3 \cdot 7$), then we'll end up with something different.

Comment: The insertion of $-1$ is maybe a bit more subtle. Note that any time you have the expression $x - y$, then that's exactly the same thing as $x + (-y)$, which in turn is the same thing as $x + (-1) \cdot y$. So, for example, the expressions
$$
13 - 7, \quad 13 + (-7), \quad 13 + (-1) \cdot 7
$$
all yield the same result.

Comment: So, the positive 1 and the -1... are they both added to keep the equation neutral? I thought maybe at first, but now I think not.

Comment: @Renoldus It is not clear what you mean when you say that they're "added to keep the equation neutral"

Comment: @Renoldus An equation is valid whenever the expressions on each side are the same (in this case, for any value of $x$). So, the equation 
$$
(x^2 + x) - (x+1) = (x^2 + x) + (-1) \cdot (x+1)
$$
is valid because both sides are the same for all values of $x$.

Comment: @Renoldus I can't speak to the **purpose** of adding in the $1$ and $(-1)$. In order for me to be able to say anything about that, you would have to provide more of the context in which this equation appears.